# Getting Date Intervals From Another Table Instead of Changing Them By Hand For Filtering

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm updating a table by using SQL UPDATE statement. There must be 4 terms in the table, namely: March, June, September and December.

The table has 6 columns and first column is named term indicates in which term other columns are calculated. Term column is already populated, other columns are empty and must be calculated. For each term I'm calculating higher offers from us, same offers, lower offers, total offers and accepted offers.

In UPDATE query I'm filtering based on the interval from the source table and because there are 4 terms after executing the query I'm changing the intervals by hand then execute it again for next term.

Is there a way to get this intervals from a table and use it instead of changing them by hand? For example March term is in between 01/01/2019-31/03/2019(DDMMYYYY), June term is in between 01/04/2019-31/06/2019, so on...

I'm changing date1, date2 columns in WHERE statement in each subquery and term column from outer query. Here is my query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_X
SET 
HIGHER_OFFERS =
  (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TABLE_Y
      WHERE (date1 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (date2 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (our_offer - creditlimit) < 0 AND
            (companyname NOT LIKE '%XXX%' AND
            companyname NOT LIKE '%XXX%')  
  ),
SAME_OFFERS = 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TABLE_Y
      WHERE (date1 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (date2 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (our_offer - creditlimit) = 0 AND
            (companyname NOT LIKE '%XXX%' AND
            companyname NOT LIKE '%XXX%')
  ),
LOWER_OFFERS =
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TABLE_Y
      WHERE (date1 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (date2 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (our_offer - creditlimit) > 0 AND
            (companyname NOT LIKE '%XXX%' AND
            companyname NOT LIKE '%XXX%')
  ),
TOTAL_OFFERS = 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TABLE_Y
      WHERE (date1 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (date2 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231')
  ),
ACCEPTED_OFFERS =
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TABLE_Y
      WHERE (date1 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (date2 BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20191231') AND
            (companyname LIKE '%XXX%' OR
            companyname LIKE '%XXX%')
  )
WHERE term = 'December';
```

Comment: and what error do you get ?

Comment: I got no error. I just asked is there a way to do it?